# PHP / AJAX beginner needs assistance

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

What I would like to do is have a basic HTML form the input fields be inside PHP so that you can fill those fields with data and submit them to a database. Once that data exists in the database I want that data to fill the input fields. I want all this to be done in java/ajax/php so my page never refreshes. But I can submit data to a MYSQL database and retrieve from it.

Example code of this would be best so I can see it and learn it.

Right now I have seen how to pull from a database and fill input with the data without page refresh. Also I have seen how to enter data into a database without the page refresh.

I can't find an example of both combined.

Comment: So you're saying that something is happening which requires you to reload your data on the page?

Comment: Here is the scenario.  input field 1 , input field 2 Enter data press the submit button. Data goes into database Mysql. Once data goes in input field 1 and 2 are now filled with that data the input fields then can not be edited. Because of a SQL query the data fills those inputs. How do I do this without the page refresh? I can do this all day in php. Need ajax and java help.

Comment: By the way, that should be JavaScript, not Java. The two are very different languages and aren't related.

Answer (score 1):

```
<form onsubmit="retrieve_data(...); return false;">
 <input type="text" name="foo" id="foo"/>
 <input type="submit"/>
</form>
<div id="ajax"></div>
<script>
 function retrieve_data(...) { ... }
 function update_form(...) { ... }
</script>
```

`retrieve_data` should call php script which stores data into DB and can output some content into `div id="ajax"`. But if you add some script, it is not executed: it needs some event to run. Therefore I suggest that your php script fills `div id="ajax"` with this:

```
<img src="..." width="0" onload="update_form()"/>
```

The only thing you need is to write functions `retrieve_data` (call php script which returns content into ajax div) and `update_form`, which updates your form fields. Your page should be updated without refresh. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you're sort of asking for everything at once!

First, you'll probably be best off using jQuery to simplify the Ajax requests.

Let's set up an example database. Open the mysql command line client, and enter

```
mysql# create database test;
mysql# use test;
mysql# create table testpage(id int auto_increment,someval int,otherval varchar(16),primary key(id));
```

Here's an example HTML page. Save this in your web root as test.php:

```
 <html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#senddata').click(function(){
            var an_int=parseInt($('#an_int').val(),10); //reads the content of the form inputs
            var a_string=$('#a_string').val();
            $.post('process.php',{"an_int":an_int,"a_string":a_string},function(data){
              if(data.result=='error'){ $('#status').text('An error occurred sending the data'); return false; }
              $('#show_int').text(data.stored_int);
              $('#show_string').text(data.stored_string);
              $('#status').text('Stored and displayed data successfully');
              })
            });
        });
    </script>
  </head>
  </body>
    <form>
      An integer: <input type='text' length='40' id='an_int'><br>
      A word: <input type='text' length='40' id='a_string'><br>
      <div id='senddata'>Send Data</div>
    </form>
    <br>
    <div id='status'>Enter data and click send to store and update.</div>
    <br>
    The Int: <div id='show_int'></div>
    The String: <div id='show_string'></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Okay, so then the PHP. Save this as process.php

```
<?php

$sent_string=preg_replace('#[^\w\d]#','',$_POST['a_string']); //will remove anything other than letters, _ and digits
$sent_int=(int)$_POST['an_int']; //will strip out any non digits, or set to 0 if not numeric at all

function pdo_connect($dbn='test')
{//connect, return a pdo connection object thing handle
try
  {
  $host='localhost';
  $user='root';
  $passw='yourpassword';
  $driver_opts = array( PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'set names utf8' );

  $db=new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbn",$user, $passw, $driver_opts);
  $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  }
catch(PDOException $err)
  {echo('Could not connect to database '.$dbn.' due to error: '.$err);return false;}

return $db;
}
$db=pdo_connect();
if(!$db){ exit; }

$sql='insert into testpage values(null,?,?)';
$insert_statement=$db->prepare($sql);

$data=array($sent_int,$sent_string);
$success=$insert_statement->execute($data);

$result=$success ? 'success' : 'error';

$result_array=array('result'=>$result,'stored_int'=>$sent_int,'stored_string'=>$sent_string);

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($result_array);
exit;
```

It's not really reading the info from the database, it's just returning what it just entered. Making a page that displays a list of the data entered so far is left as an exercise for the reader! Hope this helps.